# Skobbler Annotation disappears from map when zooming out on Android

Tags: android, skmaps

Currently, I am adding a list of annotations to a mapview with code similar to the following:

```
// Add to map view
SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation(i++);
annotation.getLocation().setLongitude(result.longitude);
annotation.getLocation().setLatitude(result.latitude);
annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(1);
annotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_PURPLE);
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_POP_OUT);
```

Yet whenever I view the annotations on the map, they disappear after I zoom out to anything under zoom level 4.0. Looking at the docs for the [Annotation](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.0/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKAnnotation.html#setMininumZoomLevel(int)) class (as well as confirming in the code), I see that the default zoom level is set to 4, yet it seems that my call to `.setMinimumZoomLevel` is ignored.

Does anyone have any insight into what is happening or if this might be a known bug within the SDK?

I'm using Skobbler 2.5 on Android.

Thanks for any help in the matter!

Comment: I have checked, the same issue for me.

Comment: And one more case, i set the miniumZoomLeve to 11 then zoom at level 10, there is no marker display on map, but try to touch to the marker's possion -> onAnnotationSelected called.

Comment: Indeed it seems that there is some inconsistency:  1. add an annotation using the absolute path to the image - you can have min zoom level 2 2. Add annotation using texture ID - you can have min zoom level 4 3. add an annotation with a drawable resource - you can have min zoom level 5. We're looking into it

Comment: Thanks for the update @Ando! To clarify, when using the absolute path image approach, the min zoom level is 2? Do you know if this issue will be addressed in the next update or should we attempt to go with the absolute path image approach workaround for the foreseeable future?

Comment: @Keith - the next update 2.5.1 won't address this issue (as the roadmap is full there), but we're looking into addressing the next update (2.6 or 3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off Ando's comment on the original question and referencing the documentation [here](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec009), I updated the code to use the workaround he described to allow annotations to show up down to zoom level 2.

Original code:

```
SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation(i++);
annotation.getLocation().setLongitude(result.longitude);
annotation.getLocation().setLatitude(result.latitude);
annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(1); // Note: this does not work
annotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_PURPLE);
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_POP_OUT);
```

Updated code:

```
SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation(i++);
annotation.getLocation().setLongitude(result.longitude);
annotation.getLocation().setLatitude(result.latitude);
annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(2);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
if (metrics.densityDpi < DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
    annotation.setImagePath(SKMaps.getInstance().getMapInitSettings().
            getMapResourcesPath() + "/.Common/icon_greypin@2x.png");
    // set the size of the image in pixel
    annotation.setImageSize(128);
} else {
    annotation.setImagePath(SKMaps.getInstance().getMapInitSettings().
            getMapResourcesPath()+ "/.Common/icon_greypin@3x.png");
    // set the size of the image in pixels
    annotation.setImageSize(256);
}
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_POP_OUT);
```

A couple things to note:

1. <strike>`.setImagePath()`</strike> and <strike>`.setImageSize()`</strike> are both deprecated methods in the latest SDK even though they're still referenced in the documentation above. Not sure if that means there is another alternative to displaying images via an absolute path approach, or if they're simply phasing this functionality out.
2. In my particular example, we're using the purple pin to display annotations, but the absolute path file name for that pin is actually called `icon_greypin`. It looks like the other pin image file name are named appropriately however.

Anyways, this served as a solution for my particular problem until the SDK is updated, so I'm marking it as the answer and I hope it helps someone else! Thanks to Ando for the step in the right direction!